# Is an STL Container of const T with a custom allocator ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Take the following code snippet:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> good;

//illegal, because std::allocator<const T> is ill-formed
std::vector<const int> bad;

//fails to compile under MSVS 2017
std::vector<const int, my_custom_allocator> X;
```

Why does X fail to compile? MSVS 2017 shows

> Error C2338 (failed static assert): The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.

It is my understanding that this is not necessarily correct.

According to 20.5.3.5 [allocator.requirements] (and [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573190/why-does-the-c-standard-forbid-containers-of-const-elements) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)), an allocator of a const T is ill-formed - but as I understand it, it is also possible to [define an allocator that only works with a single type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783177/allocator-with-no-template) (meaning, a non-templated allocator). This avoids, albeit in a slightly pedantic way, the language restriction. It is also my understanding that since templates are instantiated at compile time, the default value for the vector's allocator (i.e., `std::allocator<const T>`) is never instantiated - and that, therefore, the last line does not break that rule.

Ignoring the use cases and alternatives (and the fact that `const std::vector<int>` probably solves your problem), and given a valid `my_custom_allocator`: is `std::vector<const int, my_custom_allocator>` really ill-formed?

Comment: I believe that makes `my_custom_allocator` not an allocator instead.

Comment: An allocator that works for one type, but which one? The one the container needs?

Comment: @curiousguy yes, since otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @osuka_ How can you know in advance which type of objects the container wants to allocate?

Comment: @curiousguy you’ll know because you’ll have implemented it. Regardless of that, however, the question is not about the allocator itself - but rather about the legality of a container type such as the one discussed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would still be ill-formed. According to [[allocator.requirements]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements), an allocator is supposed to work with objects of a type `T` which is [defined to be](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:desc.var.def)

> any *cv*-unqualified object type

Based on that, it would seem to me that anything that works with `const T` cannot satisfy the requirements to be an allocator and, thus, cannot be used as an allocator for a standard container…

Comment: But what about a theoretical `custom_const_allocator<T>`, which would have cv-unqualified `T` - but would have `Allocator::value_type = const T`?

Comment: [allocator.requirements] requires that the `value_type` of an allocator be a *cv*-unqualified object type. Thus, this would not be legal…

Comment: Ah, you seem to be correct. There are no requirements imposed on `value_type` itself, but since it must be *identical* to `T`, it would seem that it would be illegal.

Comment: Well, the fact that `value_type` must be identical to `T` (where `T` is the type the allocator is an allocator for) is what I would call a requirement imposed on `value_type`… ;-)

Comment: You've just proved to me that I can write neither C++, nor English. What a day!